# UIWebView inside sub-ViewController not loading

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a ViewController (with a UIWebView) and a CreateEntryViewController (with another UIWebView). When I change to CreateEntryViewController with `[self presentViewController:vc2 animated:TRUE completion:nil];`.

On this load I call an `-(void)updateView` which performs the following:

```
- (void)updateView {
    NSLog(@"CreateEntryViewController: updateView");
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        NSString *urlAddress = @"http://google.com/";
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAddress];
        NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [createEntryWebView loadRequest:requestObj];
    }
}
```

I can confirm that the log message is shown, so the function is called, but my UIWebView remains empty - leading me to believe it is not linked correctly with `createEntryWebView`. I have initialized it in the same way as I've done in the main ViewController (which works).

I am new to Objective C and iOS development - is there something I could have missed? Delegate? Something?

Thanks in advance,
Caspar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you added `UIWebViewDelegate` to your class? if your `createEntryWebView` is an `IBOutlet` then you should make sure it is connected properly and delegate porperty in IB is set to `File's Owner`. if it is not an `IBOutlet` then make sure you initialize and set the delegate to `createEntryWebView` properly.

something like this

```
createEntryWebView.delegate=self;
```

to find out if your webview is responding to your requests , implement the following delegate methods from `UIWebViewDelegate`

```
– webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:
– webViewDidStartLoad:
– webViewDidFinishLoad:
– webView:didFailLoadWithError:
```

Comment: That sounds reasonable, thanks. I'll have a chance to try it out tomorrow.